# window.open(url, '_blank') works in local server, but it does not on stage or in production url. It is missing a certain value after domain value

Tags: angular, router

I have an edit button and eventually want to open a new tab with the edit page.

Here is the code in angular:

**customer.component.html**

```js
<button
pButton
pRipple
type="button"
icon="pi pi-pencil"
class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-sm"
(click)="openWindow(customer.customerId)"
pTooltip="edit"
tooltipPosition="bottom"
></button>
```

**customer.component.ts**

```js
openWindow(customerId: number){
    const url = this.router.serializer(
      this.router.createUrlTree([`/customers/edit/${customerId}`])
    );

    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

It does work as expected in local server. The edit domain is `http://localhost:3000/project/customers/edit/1111`.

However, when I pushed the code, a 404 error occurred. I looked at the domain and it is not the right one (i.e. `http://exampledomain.com/customers/edit/1111`).
This should be `http://exampledomain.com/stage_project/customers/edit/1111`

Anyone, please advise me?

Comment: You need to provide the baseHref : https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF